# Only select first row of repeating value in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, ms-access, duplicates

I have table that has a column that may have same values in a burst. Like this:

```
+----+---------+
| id |   Col1  | 
+----+---------+
| 1  | 6050000 |
+----+---------+
| 2  | 6050000 |
+----+---------+
| 3  | 6050000 |
+----+---------+
| 4  | 6060000 |
+----+---------+
| 5  | 6060000 |
+----+---------+
| 6  | 6060000 |
+----+---------+
| 7  | 6060000 |
+----+---------+
| 8  | 6060000 |
+----+---------+
| 9  | 6050000 |
+----+---------+
| 10 | 6000000 |
+----+---------+
| 11 | 6000000 |
+----+---------+
```

Now I want to prune rows where the value of `Col1` is repeated and only select the first occurrence.
For the above table the result should be:

```
+----+---------+
| id |   Col1  | 
+----+---------+
| 1  | 6050000 |
+----+---------+
| 4  | 6060000 |
+----+---------+
| 9  | 6050000 |
+----+---------+
| 10 | 6000000 |
+----+---------+
```

How can I do this in SQL?
**Note that only burst rows should be removed and values can be repeated in non-burst rows!** `id=1` & `id=9` are repeated in sample result.

EDIT:
I achieved it using this:

```
select id,col1 from data as d1
where not exists (
    Select id from data as d2
    where d2.id=d1.id-1 and d1.col1=d2.col1 order by id limit 1)
```

But this only works when ids are sequential. With gaps between ids (deleted ones) the query breaks. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `id` guaranteed to be sequential (without gaps or duplicates)?

Comment: So you use SQlite and MS Access and cannot use window functions like `row_number()`, right?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Yes i'm using SQlite & MS Access & as I searched they didn't support LAG & LEAD and i didn't found any window functions like row_numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `EXISTS` semi-join to identify candidates:

#### Select wanted rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  col1 = t.col1
    AND    id = t.id - 1
    )
ORDER  BY id;
```

#### Get rid of unwanted rows:

```
DELETE FROM tbl AS t
-- SELECT * FROM tbl t  -- check first?
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  col1 = t.col1
    AND    id   = t.id - 1
    );
```

This effectively deletes every row, where the preceding row has the same value in `col1`, thereby arriving at your set goal: only the first row of every burst survives.

I left the commented `SELECT` statement because you should **always** check what is going to be deleted before you do the deed.

#### Solution for non-sequential IDs:

If your RDBMS supports [CTEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expression) and [window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_%28SQL%29#Window_function) (like PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ... but *not* SQLite [prior to v3.25](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html), MS Access or MySQL [prior to v8.0.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)), there is an elegant way:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM   tbl
    )
SELECT id, col1
FROM   cte c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   cte
    WHERE  col1 = c.col1
    AND    rn   = c.rn - 1
    )
ORDER  BY id;
```

Another way doing the job **without those niceties** (should work for you):

```
SELECT id, col1
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  (
    SELECT col1 = t.col1
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  id < t.id
    ORDER  BY id DESC
    LIMIT  1) IS NOT TRUE
ORDER  BY id;
```

Comment: Hi thanks can it be developed to cover unsequential ids? (using `exists` and `order`)

Comment: @Snigger: I guess. Please define "unsequential ids". Preferably by editing your question for everybody to read in a nice format. Ah you already did. That should do, thanks.

Comment: the second query works well except that it doesn't select the first row (which is always the first occurrence) so I edited your query like this: `SELECT id, col1
FROM   tbl
WHERE (
    SELECT t.col1 = tbl.col1
    FROM   tbl AS t
    WHERE  t.id < tbl.id
    ORDER  BY id DESC
    LIMIT  1)==0 OR NOT exists(SELECT tt.id FROM tbl AS tt WHERE tt.id < tbl.id)
ORDER BY id` for SQlite

Answer (score 5):

```
select min(id), Col1 from tableName group by Col1
```

Comment: this removes all repeated rows but if you check my sample result you will see that id 1 and id 9 both have same values for `Col1` but both are in results because there where another value (6060000 on id 4 to id 8) between them.

Answer (score 2):

If your RDBMS supports Window Aggregate functions and/or LEAD() and LAG() functions you can leverage them to accomplish what you are trying to report. The following SQL will help get you started down the right path:

```
SELECT id
     , Col AS CurCol
     , MAX(Col)
       OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS PrevCol
     , MIN(COL)
       OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS NextCol
FROM MyTable
```

From there you can put that SQL in a derived table with some CASE logic that if the `NextCol` or `PrevCol` is the same as `CurCol` then set `CurCol = NULL`. Then you can collapse eliminate all the id records `CurCol IS NULL`.

If you don't have the ability to use window aggregates or LEAD/LAG functions your task is a little more complex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I'm using SQlite and MS Access as DBMS and they don't have this ability

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is always sequential, with no gaps or repetitions, as per your comment, you could use the following method:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM atable t1
  LEFT JOIN atable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id + 1 AND t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

The table is (outer-)joined to itself on the condition that the left side's `id` is one greater than the right side's and their `Col1` values are identical. In other words, the condition is *‘the previous row contains the same `Col1` value as the current row’*. If there's no match on the right, then the current record should be selected.

---

**UPDATE**

To account for non-sequential `id`s (which, however, are assumed to be unique and defining the order of changes of `Col1`), you could also try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM atable t1
  LEFT JOIN atable t2 ON t1.id > t2.id
  LEFT JOIN atable t3 ON t1.id > t3.id AND t3.id > t2.id
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
  AND (t2.id IS NULL OR t2.Col1 <> t1.Col1)
```

The third self-join is there to ensure that the second one yields the row directly preceding that of `t1`. That is, if there's no match for `t3`, then either `t2` contains the preceding row or it's got no match either, the latter meaning that `t1`'s current row is the top one.

Comment: Hi thanks can it be developed to cover unsequential ids? (using `exists` and `order`)