# sqlite select only first row with unique cell in column

Tags: sqlite

I need to select from sqlite table based on column "categ" first row with unique name.
Here is what I have:

```
|id     |val    |categ
|1      |any1   |categ1
|2      |any2   |categ1
|3      |any3   |categ2
|4      |any4   |categ2
|5      |any5   |categ2
|6      |any6   |categ3
|7      |any7   |categ3
|8      |any8   |categ4
|9      |any9   |categ4
|10     |any10  |categ4
```

And here is what I need as result:

```
|id     |val    |categ
|1      |any1   |categ1
|3      |any3   |categ2
|6      |any6   |categ3
|8      |any8   |categ4
```

First row are column names. And filter should be done by column "categ".
I need to get as results 1 row from each categ.
The name of categs are just as example, in real table the "categ" names are person names (Example: John, Mary etc)

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683547/only-select-first-row-of-repeating-value-in-a-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY to get one row per category. In SQLite, you can [use MIN() to control which row in a group to return](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg):

```
SELECT min(id) AS id, val, categ
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY categ;
```

Comment: Perfect, worked exactly like I wanted it. Thanks @CL

Answer (score -1):

Use Group By clause on Categ column

Comment: Please demonstrate how the asker can use `GROUP BY` to get the first `val` for each `categ`.